# How to replicate ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP_STD_TBL?

Tags: oracle, tablespace

On a remote DB I get "ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace SOME_TABLESPACE" exception when running a procedure.

I want to replicate the exception locally.

I tried the following:

REVOKE unlimited tablespace FROM MY_USER;

ALTER USER MY_USER quota 1k on USERS;

but I get a different exception after applying this changes.

Comment: So do we have to read your mind and guess what is *that different* exception? Please, describe the issue assuming we have no any information about your system. And what do you want to achieve after you reproduce the same exception locally? Temp usage depends on many factors and it will be hard to guess upfront for the specific query. It would be better to monitor your query and try to tune it first

Comment: @astentx I think it was "no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'", but it is not really important, cause I want to get "ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP_STD_TBL?".